# How to assign the same var type variable to different linq to sql result sets?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a scenario:

For example

I have this

```
var resultSet;
```

Now this I need to assign to multiple LINQ-SQL result like

```
if(somecondition)
{
   resultSet= (from t1 in table1 where t1.id= 1 select new CustomClass {name='test1'})
}
if(anotherCondition)
{
   resultSet = (from t2 in table2 where t2.id= 1 select new CustomClass {name='test2'})
}

resultSet= resultSet.OrderByDescending(d => d.Id)
                              .ToArray()

var count= resultSet.Count();
```

but issue is that if i take `resultSet` globally then it doesn't work and if I assign `NULL` it won't work since it cannot be assigned to null and if i assign it something like `var resultSet= new Object()` then functions i.e. `.count(), orderby` etc. won't work.

what should I do?

I need to use the same variable and for different `dbcontext` tables but with same class.

Comment: `var resultSet;` is not valid c#. `var` is not a type, it is replaced by the compiler with type of the initialization expression. The variable `resultSet` cannot change its type.

Comment: What about like this?

Array<CustomClass> resultSet = null;

resultSet= (from t1 in table1 where t1.id= 1 select new CustomClass {name='test1'}).ToArray();

resultSet= resultSet.OrderByDescending(d => d.Id) .ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define `resultSet` as `IEnumerable<CustomClass>`

```
IEnumerable<CustomClass> resultSet = null;// Must be assigned to something

if(somecondition)
{
   resultSet= (from t1 in table1 where t1.id= 1 select new CustomClass {name='test1'})
}
if(anotherCondition)
{
   resultSet = (from t2 in table2 where t2.id= 1 select new CustomClass {name='test2'})
}

resultSet= resultSet.OrderByDescending(d => d.Id)
                              .ToArray()

var count= resultSet.Count();
```

You could also choose to use `IQueryable<CustomeClass>` but then you'd want to remove the `ToArray()` part.

Answer (score 0):

What is sounds like what you want is to scope the result set outside of the code that populates it:

for example,

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public IEnumerable<CustomClass> ResultSet { get; private set; } = new List<CustomClass>();

    //Pseudo: values and conditions are just indicative of logic.
    public void SomeMethod(someValue, someOtherValue)
    {
        IQueryable<CustomClass> resultSet = null;
        if(somecondition)
            resultSet = (from t1 in table1 where t1.id= 1 select new CustomClass {name='test1'});
       else if(anotherCondition)
            resultSet = (from t2 in table2 where t2.id= 1 select new CustomClass {name='test2'});
       else
           throw new ArgumentException("Invalid combination of conditions.");
         
    ResultSet = resultSet.OrderByDescending(d => d.Id)
        .ToArray();

    var count= resultSet.Count;

}
```